# whats the purpose of a registry class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Can someone explain why a registry class is needed in an MVC framework?

Is it to load libraries? whats the general idea behind the creation of a registry? what data should be handled by a registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_registry

> The Registry provides a mechanism for storing data globally in a well managed fashion, helping to prevent global meltdown.

Basically it means the registry is a place to store your variables/objects that you need in a global scope without polluting the global namespace of your application. It has nothing to do with MVC per se but many MVC frameworks also utilize the Registry pattern.

It allows you to *store* a variable in one place and *retrieve* it in another place without having to resort to all kinds of complex routines or magic to retrieve your variables.

Taking Zend Framework for example you create a Zend_Navigation object and store it in the [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) at bootstrap. Then lateron you can easily retrieve it from the registry in one of you controllers or other classes.

Comment: so a registry needs to be statically called? or via an object?

Comment: Most Registry implementations are indeed static. `Zend_Registry::get()` and `Zend_Registry::set()` for example.

Comment: Do not use static registry just because Zend does it, Zend is not even close to being a pillar of good development standards. Instead pass the state around to your MVC objects. This allows you to use multiple registries (or state objects) in the single execution should that be needed. Also, not having it static keeps testing much better to handle.

Comment: @kristovaher as I said most of them implement a static interface, i'm not saying this is the best but most of the existing libraries do. We could elaborate a lot further and explain DI for example which solves some of the issues the Registry pattern has but that's not the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The Registry Class more is more like data holder object loader and so on. You can add Data to registry in controller  and  get it from view.
A little example.

```
  Class Registry
    {
         protected $data = array();
         private $loadClasses;

         public function getData($name){

            return isset($this->data[$name])?$this->data[$name]:null;
         }
         public function setData($name,$value)
         {
            $this->data[$name] = $value;
         }
         public function addData($name,$value)
         {
             $this->data[$name][] = $value;
         }


         public function &singletonLoad($class) 
         {
            if(isset($this->loadClasses[$class])) 
            {
               return $this->loadClasses[$class] ;  
            }
            if(class_exists($class)) 
            {
                return $this->loadClasses[$class] = new $class();
            }else 
            {
                return false;
            }
         }



    }


    class AController  extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction() 
        {
            $this->registsry->setData('name','John')  ;
        }

    }


     class AView  extends View
    {
        public function getName() 
        {
            return  $this->registsry->getData('name') ;
        }

    }
```